# Android Appwidget not showing in launcher after installation

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Q. Android Appwidget not showing in launcher immediately after installation:-

**What I have already tried and does not work consistently**

1. Included stub Activity with MAIN and LAUNCHER intent filter
2. Included this code in onCreate() of this stub activity

   ```
   sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME));
   ```

**What works consistently**

1. Reboot
2. Change orientation of device with widget list opened. This causes a refresh of the widget list and shows the newly installed widget.

So is there something I am missing ? It creates poor perception when user installs widget and does not find the widget in the widget list. Generally leads to uninstall :(

Comment: I think you should accept Eric's answer. He's right: it's a problem out of our hands. I'm in your same situation with my appwidget, included a main activity giving users a helping hand (not did send the broadcast though) and have experienced a similar result: it *sometimes* work, many users need to reboot. Only thin I can do is to answer users quickly when this issue arises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [an open issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24208) for some devices and OS versions (mainly ICS it seems). What are you running? It should be the same issue which is, hopefully, soon fixed. I think the best option for you would be to inform your customers about this bug and that it is out of your hands. You should then also provide an easy way to fix it! An informed customer is less likely to have false expectations and uninstall your widget.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it on ICS to JB 4.2. Same behaviour on different devices. Also created a startup screen informing customer about how to find widget by tilting screen. But sometimes I get the same comment "widget not found" and 1 star.

Comment: If I have X downloads then increase in active installs is around 10% of X. There is a possibility that users are not finding widget and just leaving.

Comment: Unfortunately, users have expectations that they want to see met. In today's society with the abundance of software, if something does not work right away, even if it isn't your fault, users will discard it. That is just the way it is and there is nothing you can do about it.